# Quantile in normal distribution

Tags: statistics

Let's think that we have a random variable $X \sim N(0,1)$. And is it true that quantile(let's call it z) z($\alpha$/2) = - z($1- \alpha/2$)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is true for any distribution that is symmetric around zero.